# how to select an exact match using grep in R to subset a dataframe

Tags: r, regex

I have tried using **fixed** as in`data[grep(14,data$x,fixed=TRUE),]`, but it matches rows where `data$x == 14`, `data$x == 1144` or any row with 14 in its `data$x` field.

Comment: `data[grep("^14$", data$x),]`. But it isn't clear if you only want strings with `"14"` or also `"num. 14"`

Comment: And if you are subsetting a data frame, you probably do not need `grep`. Try `data[data$x == 14,]`

Comment: @PierreLafortune you are right. I really don't need grep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\\b` in your regexp to detect word boundaries.

For ex:

```
data <- data.frame(field=c(14,1144,"test14test","test 14 test"))
grep("\\b14\\b",data$field)
#[1] 1 4
```

If `data$field` are just numbers, @Pierre Lafortune's solution might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The grep() function matches a pattern, which is why it is matching both "14" and "1144" As Pierre pointed out in his comment, you can change the pattern to the regular expression "^14$". ^ requires that it starts with that pattern, and $ requires that it ends with that pattern. That will get you an exact match.

Another good way to subset data is by using the subset() function.

```
data_subset <- subset(data, x == "14")
```